# File Manager which can show connections between files in the same directory?

Tags: filesystems, file-management

Without creating *new* directories, is there a file manager that can illustrate relationships between files/folders in the same directory?

For example, I would like to turn something like this:
[image]

Into this:
[image]

Is there a file manager, or viewer with this kind of capability?

Comment: what would the connections be? What metadata needs to be read?

Comment: @Rich The connections would do nothing other than provide convenience to the user. So metadata could be as simple as A->B1. B1->C1. etc.

Comment: How does the manager know this? What are the links? how are they created? is it contents?

Comment: The links would be created by the user.  They decide how the files are associated based on their own mental model.  It wouldn't change the filesystem or files.  The manager can know whichever way it needs to.  Whether I need to place a configuration file in each directory, or the manager stores these configuration options elsewhere.  Now obviously it would only work using a certain file viewer, but that is expected. I remember in Windows XP(and probably others) I could kinda fake this because it had a folder view option where the files didn't snap to a grid; much like how most desktops behave.

Comment: Basically a file manager that works as a *mind map*? Have you checked Coggle or Freemind? Not file managers but the typical tools used for similar requirements.